# How to resolve nuget packages when using git submodules for VS Solution

Tags: .net, git, visual-studio, nuget, git-submodules

I have two repositories. The first one is big integration repository with lots of projects in it. The second one is relatively small solution with a number of projects in it that is being developed separately and then integrated into the first solution.

I added second git repository to the first git repository as submodule, so I have such file structure:

```
MainSolution.sln
SomeProject1
SomeProject2
packages
my-second-project
  SecondSolution.sln
  SomeProject3
  SomeProject4
```

And my separate repository (after restoring nuget packages) looks like

```
SecondSolution.sln
SomeProject3
SomeProject4
packages
```

Now, each project references nuget restore packages folder separately. So None of my projects from added submodule were able to restore their nuget packages because they searched for `my-second-project/packages` folder which doesn't exist. And if I reinstall nuget packages, then I can see in my git diffs that they begin to reference root packages folder (like `..\..\packages`).

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Have you set any "repositoryPath" in the nuget.config file, which located in the .sln folder or %Appdata%\NuGet\NuGet.config? If yes, Could you please share the repositoryPath  settings to me?

Comment: I resolved issue by changing `..\packages` everywhere in all `*.csproj` files to `$(SolutionDir)\packages`. Works pretty well. Simple script covers it: `find -name "*.csproj" | xargs sed -i 's/\.\.\\packages/$(SolutionDir)\\packages/g'`

Comment: Glad to know that you have resolved this issue. Could you please write your answer and mark it which is benefit to other communities who has the same problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I resolved issue by changing `..\packages` everywhere in all `*.csproj` files to `$(SolutionDir)\packages`. Works pretty well. Simple script covers it:

```
find -name "*.csproj" | xargs sed -i 's/\.\.\\packages/$(SolutionDir)\\packages/g'
```

Don't know why nuget doesn't behave this way by default, now I need to re-run this script whenever I update/install nuget packages.

Comment: Excellent! Extremely minor nitpick: The expanded value of `$(SolutionDir)` already contains a trailing backslash, so I'd change `..\packages` to `$(SolutionDir)packages`.